# SharePoint workflow does not start for automatically uploaded documents

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, documents

I have a service that automatically uploads documents to a SharePoint 2013 Document Library. I created a simple workflow that starts when a new item is created and just sends an email notification; however, the workflow only starts when I manually add a document and not when it's uploaded by the service. Thank you in advance for any ideas on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add some code to start a workflow after the app does its stuff:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

static void StartWorkflow(SPListItem listItem, SPSite spSite, string wfName)
{
    SPList parentList = listItem.ParentList;
    SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection = parentList.WorkflowAssociations;
    foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection)
    {
        if (association.Name == wfName)
        {
            association.AutoStartChange = true;
            association.AutoStartCreate = false;
            association.AssociationData = string.Empty;
            spSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, association, association.AssociationData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have attached your workflow to the list, the workflow should be triggered automatically. 
I found some case like this before. please check [here][1]

[1]: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/workflow-not-triggered-via-custom-webpart-but-works-if-add-item-from-ui .

Comment: The workflow only triggers when I upload a file through UI, not when it's uploaded automatically (using System Account). The line   'site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(item, myAssociation, myAssociation.AssociationData);'   asks for **item** (SharePoint entity) which I don't have a way to specify in the code.