# Why does SharePoint workflow fail to start when document uploaded by another workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Office 365 - SharePoint 2013 Workflow

I have two Document Libraries:

1. **Work In Progress**
2. **Archived**

There is a SharePoint 2013 List Workflow **Add Document** attached to **Work In Progress** with attribute "*Start workflow automatically when an item is created*" set.  This workflow copies the new document to the **Archived** library.

There is a SharePoint 2013 List Workflow **Archive Rename** attached to **Archived** with attribute "*Start workflow automatically when an item is created*" set.  This workflow renames the new document.

Both Workflows were designed in SharePoint Designer - there is no custom code.

The **Archive Rename** Workflow is not starting when the document is copied by the **Add Document** Workflow, although it does start correctly when a document is uploaded manually through the UI.

I've seen a similar topic here [SharePoint workflow does not start for automatically uploaded documents][1]

[1]: [SharePoint workflow does not start for automatically uploaded documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861247/sharepoint-workflow-does-not-start-for-automatically-uploaded-documents) but that is concerned with custom code.  This project cannot use custom code.

Does anyone have any ideas why the second Workflow is not being triggered?

Thanks

Edward

Answer (score 1):

This is done to prevent workflow recursion. You can start another workflow using Start Sharepoint 2010 workflow action or rest api. There is one possile solution in details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2.aspx